# Rails + omniauth + facebook - csrf detected

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I'm working on logging in a site via existing `facebook` account. So I registered a facebook application and stored **api** and **secret** in `development.rb` and `production.rb` files. Then I used `omniauth-facebook gem` + `devise gem` to implement this. It works perfect.

By the way, an user can login either by internal authentication (by devise) or by usig facebook account.

However there is a weird issue. It works perfect **only** if I login into facebook account in that I registered an application.

So I registered another facebook account that didn't have an application used in my Rails application and tried to login. It caused an error "An error occurred. Please try again later." ... **"Could not authenticate you from Facebook-Account because "Csrf detected""**

I tried to use 1.4.0 omniauth-facebook gem instead of 1.4.1 one but it also caused an error "`must pass either a`code`parameter or a signed request (via`signed_request`parameter or a`fbsr_XXX`cookie)`"

Gems

```
oauth2 (0.8.0) 
omniauth (1.1.0) 
omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.0) 
omniauth-facebook (1.4.1) 
warden (1.2.1)
devise (2.1.2)
```

Your ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue as well, turns out I still had "sandbox" mode enabled in my Facebook application. Sounds like this may be your issue as well :)

If not, could you please post any related log entries?

Comment: This may be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597130/omniauth-facebook-keeps-reporting-invalid-credentials

Answer (score 3):

For me, I needed to add `provider_ignores_state: true` to my Omniauth config:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], {
  strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook,
  provider_ignores_state: true
}
```

This is on `omniauth-facebook` gem version 1.6.0.

There is more info also at https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue when I deleted 'omniauth.rb' because I already have this config below in devise.rb:

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_ID"], ENV["FB_SECRET"],
    scope: 'email',
    info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name',
    image_size: 'large',  # 50x50, guaranteed ratio
    secure_image_url: true
```

Remember to restart the sever to test.