# Rails 4 + omniauth facebook - csrf detected

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am working on my RoR4 app to enable users to login via existing `facebook` account. I registered a facebook app (a live and tested version) and stored its api and secret in `development.rb`. I used omniauth-facebook and devise gems and encountered an "`Csrf detected`" problem.

My application's code is highy inspired from this blogpost:
http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

I did see a solution from a stackoverflow post dated 2 years ago ([Rails + omniauth + facebook - csrf detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970977/rails-omniauth-facebook-csrf-detected)) - but latest omniauth-facebook version is much greater than the one posted. Either way, I tried to roll back to omniauth-facebook gem to version 1.4.1 and I still encountered this problem.

Gems

```
oauth2 (1.0.0)
omniauth (1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
```

Ideas?

Errors log

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have similar issue with device and omniauth-facebook, but it was my mistake.

Previously  I have added facebook app id and secrets in both `device.rb` and `omniauth.rb` initializer (Both are initializers in `config/initializers` folder ). I removed these facebook configurations from `omniauth.rb` and restarted server, and It works.

Please check your `device.rb` and and other omniauth related initializers.

May be it work..

Comment: you mean `devise.rb` ?

Comment: I had the same issue. I had put my app id and secret in both the devise initializer and a omniauth initializer. Removing the duplicate credentials in devise.rb fixed the issue.