# CORS issue with Facebook JS SDK cookie and omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cors, omniauth-facebook

I'm implementing Sign In with Facebook on my project, which consists in two applications:

- **Frontend**: plain HTML+CSS+JS;
- **Backend**: Rails 5 API (omniauth 1.3.1, omniauth-facebook 3.0.0);

Even in my local environment, both applications run on different domains (`frontend.dev.azk.io` and `api.dev.azk.io`).

I run the FB SDK in my frontend app, and once the login succeeds, I should ping the OAuth callback (`http://api.dev.azk.io/api/v1/users/auth/facebook/callback`) so that `omniauth-facebook` could access the `fbsr_XXX` cookie, parse it and exchange the current `accessToken` for a long term one.

The main issue is that the cookie set by FB SDK belongs to the frontend domain and isn't sent in the header of the request to the API, i.e. `omniauth-facebook` cannot access it:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! no_authorization_code: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError, must pass either a `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)
```

At this point, I thought in two possible approaches:

1) Check CORS and AJAX configs so that the cookie could be sent in the request to the API;

2) [Parse](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb#L122) the FB response in the frontend (using [this algorithm](https://www.sitekickr.com/snippets/javascript/facebook-signed-request-javascript-decode)) and send the [`code` attribute](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb#L134) to the API;

### Approach 1

Inspired by this [incredibly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032474/cors-issue-with-rails-4-omniauth-facebook-rack-cors-heroku) here in SO, I've made the following configurations:

*routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, path_prefix: 'api/v1', controllers: {
  sessions:           'api/v1/sessions',
  registrations:      'api/v1/registrations',
  omniauth_callbacks: 'api/v1/omniauth_callbacks',
}
```

*application.rb*

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'frontend.dev.azk.io'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      credentials: true,
      methods: [:get, :put, :post, :patch, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```

*devise.rb*

```
config.omniauth :facebook, oauth_providers['facebook']['app_id'], oauth_providers['facebook']['secret'], {
  scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_about_me,public_profile',
  provider_ignores_state: true
}
```

*Client Application*

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.dev.azk.io/api/v1/users/auth/facebook/callback',
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
}) . . .
```

However, this isn't enough for sending the `fbsr_XXX` cookie (present in the browser). Is there anything I'm missing?

### Approach 2

Since `omniauth-facebook` can't access the aforementioned cookie, I've decided to parse the `signedRequest` value returned by FB and send the [`code` attribute](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb#L134) for the API.

However, seems that `omniauth-facebook` generates the `callback_url`, which mismatch with the one used in the previous request:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"BavpcDFblHy"}}
```

---

I really don't like the 2nd approach, I think the first one is way more elegant. I think this process should be simple, probably I'm missing something silly.

Comment: in my case, using Frontend & API backend, I no longer use cookies because APIs should be stateless, I use JsonWebTokens (JWT). When you call the FB SDK login from the Frontend you should receive the token on the frontend and store it on browser's local storage. then, in any transaction with the api you should send the token, you shouldn't store the token on the api to keep it stateless